# Custom gauge chart in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to create something like this:

[image]

How can I do that in flutter? I can't find any similar lib for that.

Comment: I created a lib for that : https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator  ,  check the samples : https://github.com/diegoveloper/flutter_percent_indicator/blob/master/example/lib/sample_circular_page.dart    , the property is 'arcType'

Comment: can I achive look like on my picture? @diegoveloper

Comment: yes, check the samples of circular percent indicator

Comment: I almost done expected indicator look. Only one thing left: rounded edge of arcBackgroundColor. Can I do that in your lib? @diegoveloper

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom CircularProgressIndicator using CustomPainter.

```dart
class CustomCircularProgress extends CustomPainter {
  final double value;

  CustomCircularProgress({required this.value});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

    canvas.drawArc(
      Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: 170, height: 170),
      vmath.radians(140),
      vmath.radians(260),
      false,
      Paint()
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..color = Colors.black12
        ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
        ..strokeWidth = 20,
    );
    canvas.saveLayer(
      Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: 200, height: 200),
      Paint(),
    );

    const Gradient gradient = SweepGradient(
      startAngle: 1.25 * math.pi / 2,
      endAngle: 5.5 * math.pi / 2,
      tileMode: TileMode.repeated,
      colors: <Color>[
        Colors.blueAccent,
        Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      ],
    );
    canvas.drawArc(
      Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: 170, height: 170),
      vmath.radians(140),
      vmath.radians(260 * value),
      false,
      Paint()
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
        ..shader = gradient
            .createShader(Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height))
        ..strokeWidth = 20,
    );
    canvas.restore();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Then use CustomPaint to render the CustomPainter on the Screen.

```dart
CustomPaint(painter: CustomCircularProgress(value: 0.75))
```

Complete Sample

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart' as vmath;
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
    )..addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    controller.repeat(reverse: true);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: CustomPaint(painter: CustomCircularProgress(value: controller.value)),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomCircularProgress extends CustomPainter {
  final double value;

  CustomCircularProgress({required this.value});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

    canvas.drawArc(
      Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: 170, height: 170),
      vmath.radians(140),
      vmath.radians(260),
      false,
      Paint()
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..color = Colors.black12
        ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
        ..strokeWidth = 20,
    );
    canvas.saveLayer(
      Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: 200, height: 200),
      Paint(),
    );

    const Gradient gradient = SweepGradient(
      startAngle: 1.25 * math.pi / 2,
      endAngle: 5.5 * math.pi / 2,
      tileMode: TileMode.repeated,
      colors: <Color>[
        Colors.blueAccent,
        Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      ],
    );
    canvas.drawArc(
      Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: 170, height: 170),
      vmath.radians(140),
      vmath.radians(260 * value),
      false,
      Paint()
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
        ..shader = gradient
            .createShader(Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height))
        ..strokeWidth = 20,
    );
    canvas.restore();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

[image: Demo]